# Should I report non-significant results?

Tags: spss, kruskal-wallis-test, reporting

I've run a Kruskal Wallis test, and for some of the questions the p value is not significant. Would I report this in the same way as if it was significant, stating the df, test statistic and p-value? So it would be something like this a Kruskal Wallis test was conducted but the results were found not to be significant H(3) = 2.119, p>0.05 (or would I state the exact p value here (.548))

Comment: Do not publish non-significant results. Otherwise, you'll bias publication bias.

Comment: But publication bias isn't a good thing in itself? Anyway, I'm not 'publishing' the results so to speak, it's for my dissertation but thanks for your comment

Comment: Dragonfly, The comment by @Mark is tongue-in-cheek.  Remember what day it is, too.  BTW, your dissertation is worthless unless it's publishable.

Comment: Do report it in our thesis. And please do read Andrew Gelman's blog regulary: http://andrewgelman.com/?s=p+value . I disagree with @whuber - you may have good stuff in your thesis even if it's not publishable. If it's accepted you have your degree.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, non-significant results are just as important as significant ones. If you are reporting any result, always include the df, test statistic, and p value. And in that case, you should state the exact p-value, rather than generalising to >0.05

Comment: Our answers agree and Conor is correct to point out that you should report the exact p-value if it is available.

Answer (score 7):

If you are publishing a paper in the open literature, you should definitely report statistically insignificant results the same way you report statistical significant results. Otherwise you contribute to underreporting bias.

Comment: But why? This implies insignificant values are just as important as significant ones. Is this because there is still a chance the “insignificant” values are actually significant. Statistical significance is not a definitive claim that something is meaningless. Yes?